# How to search for 'for-loop performance' questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, search

I have a question like this.

> What is the performance difference between
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < parentPolygon->filterList.size(); i++) {...}
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int N = parentPolygon->filterList.size();
> for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
>
>   FilterItem* filterItem = parentPolygon->filterList[i];
>   if (filterItem->getType() == oes::FT_CHILDPOLYGON) {
>       ChildPolygonFilterItem* childFilter = qobject_cast<ChildPolygonFilterItem*>(filterItem);
>       if (childFilter->m_polygon == polygon) {
>           //tries to remove it
>           bool accept = OES_DIALOGFACTORY->requestConfirmDialog(QString(OES_CONFIRM_DELETE_FROM_PARENT_FILTER).arg(polygon->getName()));
>           if (accept) {
>               parentPolygon->filterList.removeAt(i);
>           }
>           break;
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ?

Because my non-code words are very general, i.e. "what is the performance difference between",
I couldn't find a proper answer, but I have been searching for 15 minutes.

But I am afraid that if I post that question, it will be closed as a duplicate.

What can I do in such a situation?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7928147/1849664, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1242185/1849664, and this is a near-perfect match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418365/does-a-for-loop-re-evaluate-the-functions-in-its-body-in-each-iteration

Comment: thank you undo! as your name is strange, are you Golden Moderator?

Comment: what was my fault in searching? for a wrong keyword ? or for not choosing relevant word like `condition`?

Comment: This is what I searched for: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+for+loop+condition+evaluated+each&t=osx&ia=web

Comment: thanks @Undo,  duckduckgo.com seems to give more proper result than SO with my keyword. But I don't mean SO is poor. It's awesome site.

Comment: SO search is pretty bad. Use a proper search engine; you'll get better results.

Comment: you can even use `site:stackoverflow.com` on search engines to remove results from other pages.

Comment: @Tom, `site:stackoverflow` i tried this. awesome in searching(but not for my question).  I picked gold today. thanks

Comment: @DenisTurgenev Undo is a diamond moderator (no "golden" moderators... they are called diamond moderators because of the diamond symbol... no hierarchy system or anything...) as they have a diamond in their name ♦. Also, you can check someone's profile when in doubt... It will clearly state moderator (in blue) or staff (in orange). [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 thank you. but if i put 錆兎 as chinese in google translator, then it output 锖兎 in English.  ??? what rabbit? i know tu - is rabbit

Comment: What language? This could be C, C++, C#, Java, or something else. It will be a different answer each time, as the performance difference depends on the compiler and the optimizer (and/or the runtime system). In general, this is an optimization known as loop-invariant code motion. Good optimizers will apply it, but it's not always trivial to know that the stop condition is truly "invariant". If you modify the `filterList` inside the loop, its size will change, so it cannot simply be cached by the optimizer. That optimization may not be safe. Write the code you *actually mean*.

Comment: @Cody Gray, it's C++, Qt. I wrote that code. I remove one list item in a loop, but as soon as remove, I break loop, so I think I don't have a need to use filterList.size() in loop condition. In this case,  about performance difference, I am asking. when I delete child polygon, I also delete dependenices from parent polygon.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I am processing digital signals from pointcloud sensors, so here, polygon plays a role to cut point clouds by its boundary, and filterList will filter pointclouds to remove noise points. Hope this will help you to understand situation.

Comment: I don't know what "performance" means. Is that for memory, CPU time, clock-time, how well it performs in combination with other tasks or how good that code does in front of a live audience? Do know that we have sites like Computer Science in the network that are better equipped to deal with abstract issues.

Comment: @rene I mean loop time. for(; i<condition; ) vs N=condition, for (;i<N;) what is "computer science in the network"? can you give me url?

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you only ever expect it to loop one time? If you only ever expect it to loop once, it doesn't matter at all what the termination condition is.

Comment: I should find one guy in a list. and If I find it, delete and break right away. because I am sure only one exists in list. If I use QMap, then no need to loop, but this is list

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites and then find https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic or if you want to go deep: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  alternatively ask for a code review of **working code** (something that compiles and can be run by others without needing a datacentre) on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  where you ask *that you're looking for a CPU time optimization by 50%* but do share your own benchmarks when asking there.

Comment: @DenisTurgenev that is [Sabito](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Sabito) written in Kanji. It is a name so translating it would result in gibberish...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, if you have working, complete code and seek to improve it, you could ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question in this case appears to be related to the 2nd expression of the for loop, searching is mostly about knowing the term for that one. It's mostly called *loop condition* or *loop controlling expression*.

Doing a web search with `site:stackoverflow.com` on "c++ loop condition performance" gives various somewhat relevant hits. The best one appears to be this: [C++ for loop: evaluation of condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928147/c-for-loop-evaluation-of-condition)

---

> But I am afraid that if I post that question, it will be closed as a duplicate.

That's not a problem if you've done research but failed to come up with anything useful. Maybe someone else knows of a duplicate and then you'll get your question answered, even if it is closed.

Also, questions mentioning the poster's search efforts so far are often well-received. For example: "I tried searching but only came up with `<linked post>` but it doesn't really apply to my case, because..."

The kind of duplicate questions that are poorly received are often the ones with no research effort, including those that could be answered by reading the corresponding chapter in a beginner-level book about the programming language used.

Regarding performance-related questions specifically, the classic mistake people do is to ask about the performance difference between two snippets they have benchmarked, but they did so senselessly without even enabling compiler optimizations. Good performance-related questions include information about how the benchmarking was done and which compiler, target & compiler options that were used.

---

(To drift off-topic and answer the technical question here on meta... Generally, calling a function from the controlling expression is a bad idea, if we don't expect that function to give different results each call. Because the compiler may not be able to optimize away the call if the function definition isn't visible to the same translation unit.)